# SQL count relationship data

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio, winforms

I wonder how to add extra data into `dataGridView` with help of Stored Procedure

> Note: This is must probably issue with my SQL query (not sure).

I have following code which return my products data into `dataGridView`

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SampleDatabaseWalkthrough.Properties.Settings.SampleDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
  if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    cn.Open();
  using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
  {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("exec dbo.GetProducts", cn))
    {
      SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
      adapter.Fill(dt);
      dataGridViewProducts.DataSource = dt;
      dataGridViewProducts.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my default stored procedure associated to code above:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProducts]
AS
    begin
    SELECT * from Products
    end
```

***Combined of codes above works 100%***. Now I want to add relationship table data into my products query as following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProducts]
AS
    begin
    SELECT * from Products p
    Join Serials s ON s.Id = p.Id
    end
```

This stored procedure above supposed to return data of my products + count of each product serials. (i.e):

```
Name: Product 1
Origin: Local
Serials: 15 <-- this is count of relationship table
```

Screenshot:

[image: one]

**Issue**

As you see in my screenshot both my products are receiving serial numbers in column `serials` **BUT** only my product `Table` has serial number, Therefore in `serials` column of product table it should say `2` and for product `Lamp` it should say `0`

**Update**

I just noticed that in my query I should get serials like `Join Serials s ON s.ProductId = p.Id` instead I am getting them like this `Join Serials s ON s.Id= p.Id`.

BUT the problem with that is this time I'm getting 2 Table and no Lamp product in my `dataGridView` (as lamp does not have any serial associated with it).

**Any suggestion?**

## Update 2

Serials table schema

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Serials] (
    [Id]        INT           NOT NULL,
    [ProductId] INT           NOT NULL,
    [Serial]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Sold] bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Serials_Products] FOREIGN KEY ([ProductId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Products] ([Id])
);
```

Comment: Try with Left out join in your query. Share sample data and expected result in case you need help.

Comment: @AmitVerma it says `out` part is incorrect syntyax

Comment: it is _LEFT OUTER JOIN_

Comment: @AmitVerma with `left join` I get following results (screenshot) https://ibb.co/KXFrvZJ

Comment: it means serial table has 2 rows for same product id. now you have to decide based on business logic how to handle. Again I will say, share sample data and expected result.

Comment: @AmitVerma sample data not sure how to share for you, but expected result I've mentioned in my question (see i.e part)

Comment: expected result: show product table once, show serials count **2** `Serials: 15 <-- this is count of relationship table`

Comment: Sir, you are very experienced member in Stack Overflow.  you know how to ask question. I think you need serial count for every product in Serial table. You don't need serial number against that product id. Is it correct ?

Comment: @AmitVerma this is what i want https://ibb.co/dg5tsM4

Comment: @AmitVerma my experience is in another field not SQL query lets don't mix things up, and yes it's correct.

Comment: `if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)` is completely pointless: the connection is always closed when created. And correct execution of a stored procedure is `new SqlCommand("dbo.GetProducts", cn) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.*
  ,(SELECT Count(*) FROM Serials s WHERE s.ProductId = p.Id) AS Serials
FROM Products p
```

When you join onto `Serials` you end up with one row in the response for each row in the `Serials` table.
There are other ways to achieve the same resultset, but this should be the simplest to understand.

---

### UPDATE:

> what I'm trying to do is to count product serials if they are not sold yet (Sold = 0)

To demonstrate different ways to express this, you may be able to extend this concept to your needs:

```
SELECT p.*
  ,(SELECT Count(*) 
    FROM Serials s 
    WHERE s.ProductId = p.Id
      AND s.Sold = 0) AS SerialsRemaining
FROM Products p
```

You could add any number of additional columns like this, but the execution time is very inefficient.

We can use a join instead to acheive the same reocrd set, however we must include all the fields in the `Products` table in the `GROUP BY` clause for this to work:

> In this query `SUM` is used with a `CASE` expression, where `CASE` determines which column to include in the aggregate:

```
SELECT p.*
   , COUNT(s.Id) AS Total
   , SUM(CASE s.Sold WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sold
   , SUM(CASE s.Sold WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Remaining
FROM Products p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Serials s ON (s.ProductId = p.Id)
GROUP BY p.Id,p.Photo,p.Name,p.Qty,p.Origin,p.[Buy Price],p.[Sell Price],p.SN
```

For a final closure, have a look at this fiddle if you want to experiment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/64f32/2

Comment: Thank you, just it has to be like `WHERE s.ProductId = p.Id` then is working correctly.

Comment: Fair enough, that explains why your screenshot has 2 not 15 records.

Comment: Yes I've mentioned that mistake in my update part :), Is that possible to have 2 where conditions in this query?

Comment: Of course, but you really should post your table schema for us to quote definitively. the answer from @amit shows how to do the same thing using a join and group by. What is the additional field you need in the criteria?

Comment: I've shared my schema, what I'm trying to do is to count product serials if they are not sold yet (Sold = 0)

Comment: so it has 2 where, `1` where ids are matched `2` where serial is not sold

Comment: I've updated with more detail, note that using Stored Procedures for this complicates your solution, you should probably just use the SQL Command in your table adapter direct, this will help you with rapid prototyping as you can make simple changes in the app and not have to compose new SPs.

Comment: @mafortis I've added a fiddle that you can experiment with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/64f32/2

Answer (score 1):

try this. Performance of join is always better as compared to subquery.

```
SELECT P.*, COUNT(s.serail)serialCount
FROM product P
LEFT OUTER JOIN serail S ON (p.id = s.PID)
GROUP BY P.id, P.Name, P.Quantity -- _and all other columns of product table_
```